# An item with the same key has already been added. Key: ivttesting

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a scenario, where am reading data from a very large json string, and display the data using the key and value pair,  for some reason there are some keys inside the JSON file that share the same key name.

This is my code currently for reading the keys and their values and displaying it on a web page

```
public IActionResult Entry(string id)
        {
            var entry = _service.GetALLEntry(id);
            JArray json = JArray.Parse(entry.DataContent);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (JValue item in json)
            {
                JObject js = JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString());
                foreach (var _it in js)
                {
                    if (_it.Key != "fields")
                        continue;
                    foreach (var _ in _it.Value)
                    {
                        dict.Add(_.Value<string>("key") + "||" + _.Value<string>("label"), _.Value<string>("value"));
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(dict);
        }
```

How can I rename the keys that have similar name in .netcore to another name without editing the keys in the large JSON file?

Comment: `var _` - don't use underscores as variable names, because that's the convention for _discards_.

Comment: `if (_it.Key != "fields") continue;` <-- Please confirm that you only want `"fields"`, your question post doesn't say.

Comment: `JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString());` <-- **why** are you doing this? This is pointless...

Comment: Why is it called `dicts` (i.e. plural) when it's a _single_ dictionary object?

Comment: Hi @Dai yes I want fields, I have updated to single,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rename the keys that have similar name in .netcore to another name without editing the keys in the large JSON file?

Append some counter to the key when you save it to the dictionary, the code below it's the `idx` value from Linq's `.Select` overload:

```
var entry = _service.GetALLEntry(id);

JArray jarray = JArray.Parse( entry.DataContent );

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach( ( JObject obj, Int32 idx ) in jarray.OfType<JObject>().Select( ( jo, idx ) => ( jo, idx ) ) )
{
    if( obj.Property( "fields") is JProperty fp && fp.Value is JObject fieldsObj )
    {
        String? key   = fieldsObj.Property( "key" );
        String? value = fieldsObj.Property( "label" );
        if( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( key ) )
        {
            String dictKey = String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1:d}", key, idx );
            dict.Add( dictKey, value );
        }
    }
}
```